# How do i get my calendar to show public holidays locally flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how do i get my calendar to show public holidays locally flutter
like device_calendar: ^4.3.2 local Event list.

how do i get my calendar to show public holidays locally flutter.
how do i get my calendar to show public holidays locally flutter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.